# XSLT 1.0 multiple keys cross referencing and consolidating

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslkey

Thank you for taking the time to look my question.

I have an input structure (below) where each row represents a movement from one location item to another. So each row has a from location and a to location.

The target is a nested xml where a location object has some header and item level information. I need to pick distint from and to locations across all the rows and map their item level details.

Example of the input and the required transformed output.

I have a flat database extract xml that looks something like

```
<Data>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID001</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>1</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID001</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>2</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID001</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>1</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID001</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>2</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID001</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>1</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID001</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>3</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID001</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>2</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID001</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>4</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID002</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>1</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID001</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>5</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
<row>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <COMP_ID_F>HID002</COMP_ID_F>
    <ITEM_ID_F>2</ITEM_ID_F>
    <FIELDS_F> More home related data  </FIELDS_F>
    <COMP_ID_T>WID002</COMP_ID_T>
    <ITEM_ID_T>1</ITEM_ID_T>
    <FIELDS_T> More work related data</FIELDS_T>
</row>
</Data>
```

The transformed output needs to be

```
 <Target>
<Events>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
    <Movement>Home to Work</Movement>
</Events>
<Locations>
    <Home>
        <id>HID001</id>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
        </item>
    </Home> 
    <Home>
        <id>HID002</id>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
        </item>
    </Home> 
    <Work>
        <id>WID001</id>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>3</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>4</id>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>5</id>
        </item>
    </Work>
    <Work>
        <id>WID002</id>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>
    </Work>
</Locations>
</Target>
```

Now I've tried a number of options using Keys and generate id's. So please have a look and point me at where I'm going wrong. Or if there is a better way of achieving this output.

I've created 4 keys

```
<xsl:key name="fcreg" match="row" use="COMP_ID_F"/>
<xsl:key name="fcireg" match="row" use="ITEM_ID_F"/>
<xsl:key name="tcreg" match="row" use="COMP_ID_T"/>
<xsl:key name="tcireg" match="row" use="ITEM_ID_T"/>
```

My XSLT does the following logic

```
<Target>
<!--transform all events-->
<Events>
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/row">
        <!-- get movement-->
    </xsl:for-each>
</Events>

<!--transform all from locations-->
<xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[1])]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcireg', ITEM_ID_F)[COMP_ID_F=current()/COMP_ID_F][1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="items" select="key('fcreg', COMP_ID_F)[ITEM_ID_F = current()/ITEM_ID_F]"/>
        <home>
            <xsl:value-of select="COMP_ID_F"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                <item>
                    <id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID_F"/>
                    </id>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </home>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>


<!--transform all to locations-->
<xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tcreg',COMP_ID_T)[1])]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('tcreg',COMP_ID_T)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tcireg', ITEM_ID_T)[COMP_ID_T=current()/COMP_ID_T][1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="items" select="key('tcreg', COMP_ID_T)[ITEM_ID_T = current()/ITEM_ID_T]"/>
        <work>
            <xsl:value-of select="COMP_ID_T"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$items">
                <item>
                    <id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID_T"/>
                    </id>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </work>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</Target>
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is confusing. Please explain the required logic in words.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've put some words around the required logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to get the distinct `COMP_ID_F` elements, and for each distinct value, you then want to list all the distinct `ITEM_ID_F` associated with it.

Your `fcreg` key is fine, but because the `ITEM_ID_F` items depend on the value of `COMP_ID_F`, you need a concatenated key for `fcireg`

```
<xsl:key name="fcireg" match="row" use="concat(COMP_ID_F, '|', ITEM_ID_F)"/>
```

So, you start off by selecting `ITEM_ID_F` as before...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[1])]">
```

But within this, you then select the distinct `ITEM_ID_F` items for the current `COMP_ID_F` element. This is done like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[1])]">
    <home>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="COMP_ID_F" /></id>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcireg',concat(COMP_ID_F, '|', ITEM_ID_F))[1])]">
            <item>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID_F"/>
                </id>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </home>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You would have a similar one for the "T" elements

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="fcreg" match="row" use="COMP_ID_F"/>
    <xsl:key name="fcireg" match="row" use="concat(COMP_ID_F, '|', ITEM_ID_F)"/>
    <xsl:key name="tcreg" match="row" use="COMP_ID_T"/>
    <xsl:key name="tcireg" match="row" use="concat(COMP_ID_T, '|', ITEM_ID_T)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Target>
            <Events>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Data/row/Movement" />
            </Events>

        <xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[1])]">
            <Home>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="COMP_ID_F" /></id>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('fcreg',COMP_ID_F)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('fcireg',concat(COMP_ID_F, '|', ITEM_ID_F))[1])]">
                    <item>
                        <id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID_F"/>
                        </id>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Home>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="Data/row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tcreg',COMP_ID_T)[1])]">
            <Work>
                <id><xsl:value-of select="COMP_ID_T" /></id>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('tcreg',COMP_ID_T)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tcireg',concat(COMP_ID_T, '|', ITEM_ID_T))[1])]">
                    <item>
                        <id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ITEM_ID_T"/>
                        </id>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Work>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </Target>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for taking the time and explaining it. I think looking at your second for-each condition I have a better understanding of how keys work now. :)